# Is there a way to kill a task running on windows 10 with python?

Tags: python, operating-system, task

Like maybe simulating the "end task" button in the task manager? is there an API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill)

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /im yourTask.exe")
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for me